# Find rows in a table that matches by a table valued list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like the below, I want to get all users in tbl_UserPermission who has ALL the permissionid,enabledstatus combination as defined in tbl_Permission.
[tbl_userpermission sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV1gH.png)
[tbl_Permission sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMFPE.png)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_UserPermission 
(
     userid INT
    ,permissionId INT
    ,enabledstatus INT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_UserPermission VALUES (100,1,0),(100,2,1),(100,3,2),(100,4,2),(200,1,2),(200,2,0),(200,3,1),(300,1,2),(300,2,0),(300,3,1),(300,5,2)

CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_Permission
(
     permissionId INT
    ,enabledstatus INT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Permission
VALUES (1,2),(2,0),(3,1)
```

Expected Result for the query will be 200,300 as they are users who have the same (permissionId,enabledstatus) combination as defined in the tbl_Permissiontable.

**Another Scenario**

DELETE FROM tbl_permission;

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Permission
VALUES (1,2),(2,0),(3,0)

Expected Results: No userid is returned as there are no users who have the same (permissionid,enabledstatus) combination as in tbl_permission now

Comment: the use=300 has 1 extra (permissionId,enabledstatus) combination = (5,2) that does not exist in the table tbl_Permission. Or is it a typo?

Comment: Hi forpas, its not a typo User can have different types of permissions, what I want to achieve is to return any user who has the ALL the permissionid in tbl_permission and also the same enabledstatus as in tbl_permission.As long as the user statisfies the above condition that user should be returned, even if they have extra permissions in tbl_userpermission. Hope its clear

Comment: ok, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table `tbl_Permission` to `tbl_UserPermission`, then `group by userid` and set a condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
with cte as (select count(*) total from tbl_Permission)
select u.userid
from tbl_Permission p inner join tbl_UserPermission u
on u.permissionId = p.permissionId and u.enabledstatus = p.enabledstatus
group by u.userid
having count(u.permissionId) = (select total from cte)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b44fa951d9dc0584ac483a5248173922).
Results:

```
> | userid |
> | -----: |
> |    200 |
> |    300 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `inner join` to match rows between the two tables (inner join will get rid of any unmatched rows). Use `distinct` to only return unique user id's. Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U.userid
FROM tbl_UserPermission AS U
INNER JOIN tbl_Permission AS P ON U.permissionId = P.permissionId AND U.enabledstatus = P.enabledstatus;
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/17699/8/0).

Comment: Hi Josein, thanks for the quick reply what i want is users that satisfy ALL the permissionid, enabledstatus combination in tbl_permission. suppose we delete the what is in tbl_permissions DELETE FROM tbl_permission; and run the insert script below  INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Permission
VALUES (1,2),(2,0),(3,0).For the above data set it should not return any users at all, as that set of permissions is not valid for any users

Comment: Oooh, that's an interesting constraint! I'll think about it for a bit, there must be an elegant way to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not tested.

```
WITH cte_user_permission
AS
(
  SELECT u.user_id,u.permissionId,u.enabledstatus
  FROM tbl_UserPermission u
  INNER JOIN tbl_Permission p
  ON u.permission_id=p.permission_id
),
cte_permission_group
AS 
(
  SELECT u.user_id,
    STUFF((SELECT ','+CAST(g.permissionId AS nvarchar(20))+'_'+CAST(g.enabledstatus  AS nvarchar(20))
      FROM cte_user_permission g
      WHERE g.user_id=u.user_id
      ORDER BY g.permissionId
      FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(2048)'),1,1,'') AS permission_groups
  FROM cte_user_permission u
  GROUP BY u.user_id
),
cte_group
AS
(
  SELECT permission_groups
  FROM cte_permission_group
  GROUP BY permission_groups
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
SELECT u.user_id
FROM cte_user_permission u 
INNER JOIN cte_group g
ON u.permission_groups=g.permission_groups
```